# Object to string doesn't return expect result

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.4

I'm using selenium on Python and I am converting the result of

```
name = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('elementname')
```

to string.
It is returning 'WebElement' and what I am doing to convert it is

```
fname = type(name).__name__
```

I need it to return the actual element, in which case, it'd be a username of whoever's profile 'browser' is.
I just don't know why I am returned 'WebElement'.

Thanks!

(I'm sure I don't need to provide the URL and element name, right?)

Comment: what exactly is not clear about the [documentation for type()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) combined with the [documentation of the return type of find_element()](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?highlight=find_element_by_css_selector#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element) plz? I am not sure how to explain it, because to me it is obvious that the only thing that `type(WebElement()).__name__` should return is "WebElement", otherwise the world would stop spinning or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find_element_by_css_selector()` method returns a `WebElement` instance. Instead, you need the value of the `.text` property:

```
name = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('elementname')
print(name.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped a lot!